# Replace in multiple files - graphical tool for Linux

Tags: search, replace, text-editor

It needs to be graphical. No sed, awk, grep, perl, whatever. I know how to use those and I do use them now, but I need to cherry-pick each replace in 300+ files.

I want a tool where I can:

- type a search string
- type a replace string
- select a directory and file extension

and it would recursively go into each file in that directory and its sub-directories, open it and scroll to the place where search string is and offer two options:

- replace (and find next)
- find next

Nothing more. Reg.exp. support is a plus, but not required.

SOLVED: Regexxer is exactly what I needed. In case someone needs it on Slackware, [here's](http://swoes.blogspot.com/2008/10/regexxer-on-slackware-121.html) what you need to download and how to compile it (choosing correct version of each dependency can be a PITA)

Comment: Latest 0.10 source version from year 2011 with 8 downloads/week: https://regexxer.sourceforge.net/ https://sourceforge.net/projects/regexxer/ . Also available in Ubuntu based Linux distributions as installable package.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think [regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/) is exactly what you're looking for:

#### [Regexxer](http://regexxer.sourceforge.net/)

> regexxer is a nifty GUI  search/replace tool featuring Perl-style regular
> expressions. If you need project-wide substitution and you’re tired of
> hacking sed command lines together, then you should definitely give it a try.

See also the screenshot, looks a lot like what you're describing:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I would vote this down but do not have enough points to do that. regexxer does not have a multi-line search field which and therefor can only search and replace a single line. The jedit tool handles search and replace of multi-line text and is therefor a much better solution.

Comment: Agree with Farrukh, see his answer and upvote please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/189356/721073

Comment: JEdit is much more user friendly.

Comment: Warning because Regexxer is quite outdated. Cannot install it. I guess it is not for new distribution in 2022

Answer (score 8):

Emacs + dired + query-replace-regexp

For complete recipe [follow this link](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/find_replace_inter.html) (it's rather long, covering all possible alternatives),

Comment: I've used this in Emacs, and it's awesome.  It does _exactly_ what the OP wants.

Comment: Although I like Regexxer better, I'll vote you up because it is a valid solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

jEdit does exactly what you need. It is written in Java and works well in Linux, Windows and OS X (probably other operating systems also).

Comment: Interesting. I used jEdit 3-4 years ago, but don't remember that feature. Is is available via some add-on? Or maybe it was added in the meantime...

Comment: I don't know how long it's been there, but the text search dialog box allows searching for regex matches, and you can search all open files or a whole directory if you like.

Comment: SStrangely, the linux version of jedit doesn't have the multiline text area in the search and replace window (version 4.2final)

Comment: The jedit solution is the only one I have found that handles multi-line search and replace across multiiple files. The regexxer tool does not handle multi-lines in my experience. jedit on ubuntu linux indeed does have a multi-line text area using Search / Search In Directory menu action. This response should have the highest points but does not for some reason while the response with highest points (regexxer) does not support multi-line search.

Comment: jedit is user friendly. The other tools don't seem to be at all of a step up from bash so what's the point

Answer (score 5):

Lately Kate (if you use KDE) can do it, but in a very tricky way. Go to "Edit>Search in Files", and choose the folder within which your files exist.

**The trick is that only after the search results appear, you will find a text box and a button called "Replace checked". This button will do what you want.**

Comment: This is only available if you activate Kate's Search & Replace plugin.

Answer (score 3):

I use gVim for this task all the time.  I open up all the files at once, then use the commands to perform a subsitution on each file, asking for confirmation.  Generally I use < 20 files, so I open them as tabs and use this:

```
:tabdo %s/foo/bar/gc
```

gVim works fine on Windows :)  My coworkers often use Textpad to do this same thing, but I'd say gVim is much more efficient at it.

Comment: bufdo works on buffers instead of tabs, which is pretty useful.  Any way to get it to automatically save the files as it goes through buffers?

Comment: I'm not sure about saving as it goes, but you can save all of them at once when it's done with ":wa".  You could also do ":tabdo :w", I think, but I see no point to it.  And of course you could use buffers :).

Answer (score 2):

If you are a KDE user there's also [kfilereplace](http://kfilereplace.kdewebdev.org/).

Answer (score 1):

### [jdReplace](https://flathub.org/apps/page.codeberg.JakobDev.jdReplace)

Can handle very large amount of files. Easy to use, fast, and its repository is with the strong privacy and strong security Codeberg.